# Changing regedit values with python

Tags: python

I want to change the processor information registered on regedit with python. how can I do it?
I tried a little but I couldn't go beyond this stage.

```
import winreg
import ctypes

with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) 
 keyVal=OpenKey(aReg,r"HARDWARE\System\Centralprocessor\0", 7,KEY_WRITE)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that editing Registry entries can be dangerous**

**IMPORTANT:** Be sure to back up your registry before attempting to edit it.

I don't know what you really want from your code above, but I'll help in general cases.

```
from _winreg import *
keyVal = r'Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main'
try:
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
except:
    key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal)
SetValueEx(key, "Start Page", 0, REG_SZ, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/19787814/nova")
CloseKey(key)
```

In the code above, we attempt to open the following key: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main** and set the "**Start Page**" value to my stackoverflow's account. If the open fails, it's usually because the key doesn't exist, so we try to **create the key in our exception handler**. Then we use **SetValueEx** to actually set the value. Then, of course when we're done, we close the key. If you skipped the CloseKey command, you'd be fine in this case as the script is done and Python will do it for you. **However**, if you continued working on this key, you might have an access violation since it's already open. Thus, ***always close a key when you finish editing it***.

Hope it helps you to understand how it works and how you can edit reg files.